# Why did my rep and impact drop?

Tags: discussion, bug

Just curious, but when I opened the site this morning I noticed that my rep had dropped by 32 points, and impact by 1K. There was no notification in the "Recent Achievements" icon.

The other icons do not seem to be affected.

What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened is that the migration stub for your question asking [Does 'booze' include wine and beer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/526938/2085) was automatically deleted by [the Roomba daemon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513) fourteen hours ago:

[image: screen capture of deleted migration stub]

It was migrated to [Does the definition and usage of 'booze' include wine and beer? Does it depend on the geography?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239721) over on ELL last month by five community members, leaving only a bare stub hanging out on ELU as a pointer for a month. After that, it gets reaped by the clean-up daemon.

And you lost 34 points, not 32, which is completely accounted for by subtracting the three downvotes at two apiece from the the four upvotes at ten apiece for a total of 34 points gone.

Comment: It might be useful to note that equivalent points have been added to the user's ELL profile due to the migration.